# Three tab functionality on Apple Notification screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Trying to recreate the three tabs in the Notification screen.  Three tabs are 'Today' 'Missed' 'All'

Not sure how to build this.  Not even sure what this is.  UIToolBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I think I can take it from here.  Thanks Josh!!